# Longest increasing sequence in list

Tags: python-3.x

in python if you have list like [3,5,1,66,99,134,5,6] then it should be split into [[3,5],[1,66,99,134],[5,6]] and at last it should return [1,66,99,134] list. make it for any list(dynamic) without using function and classes

```
numbers = []
n = int(input("Enter How many numbers:"))
for i in range(0, n):
    numbers.append(int(input("Enter Values Of List:")))
print(numbers)

temp = [1 for x in range(0, n)]

i = 1
j = 0
count = 0

while (i <length(numbers) and j < length(numbers)):
    if numbers[j] < numbers[i]:
       if temp[j] + 1 > temp[i]:
          temp[i] = temp[j]+1
    if j == i:
        j, i = 0, i + 1
    count += 1
    if count == n:
        break
print(max(numbers))
```

Comment: The sentences above the code block seem to be a quoted task description; a horrible one, at that: for starters, it defines a sub-goal that isn't at all necessary. Please turn a quoted task description into a block quote.

Comment: (I see a sequence of comments that look reactions to comments deleted in the meantime: please put any helpful information *in your question* and delete your reactions, too.)

Comment: I see a task description and some code: *What is your question?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls = []
ls1 = []
ls2 = [ls1]
num = int(input("Enter How many numbers:"))
for n in range(num):
    numbers = int(input("Enter Numbers:"))
    ls.append(numbers)
print('List is:', ls, '\n')

for i in ls:
    if len(ls1) == 0:
        ls1.append(i)
    elif ls2[-1][-1] < i:
        ls2[-1].append(i)
    else:
        ls2.append([i])
print(ls2)

ls3 = []
for i in ls2:
    ls3.append(len(i))
print('Longest Increasing Sequence is:', ls2[ls3.index(max(ls3))])
```